# Calling function with object parameter from another function

Tags: javascript

My objective is very simple: I would like to intercept right-key and left-key press and, accordingly, execute a particular JavaScript. In particular, I have two img elements in my HTML that are basically a left and a right arrow to change a central picture:

```
<img id="goleft" onclick="changePic(this)" src="x"/>
<img id="goright" onclick="changePic(this)" src="y" />
```

The function `changePic(this)` is hence capturing the caller object (either left or right arrow) and changing the source accordingly. However, for sampling purpose, let's say here that it will just show in an alert the id of the object:

```
function changePic(obj) {
    alert("hello world");
    alert(obj.id);
}
```

Everything works fine until here. On click event, the Javascript is properly called. However, now I'm implementing a system to capture the key-right and key-left and executing the same action. The following function will capture any key-press event:

```
document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            leftArrowPressed();
            break;
        case 39:
            rightArrowPressed();
            break;
    }
};
```

...and, clearly, the two functions "leftArrow" and "rightArrow", I thought, could have simply done this:

```
function leftArrowPressed() {
    changePic(document.getElementById("goLeft"));
}

function rightArrowPressed() {
    changePic(document.getElementById("goRight"));
}
```

However, this does not work. The functions `leftArrowPressed` and `rightArrowPressed` are properly called (tested with an alert) but the function `changePic` is called (because I see the alert "hello world" popping-up but it fails on "obj.id" call). So I believe this issue is related to the way I pass the object from the caller to the listener function: could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

P.s. I'm a newbie of this language, so please don't hesitate to remark me anything that I've thought is unrelevant for answering the question but actually is not.

Comment: Just for info, I've voted to close my own question as this is not a content that will help any other user in the future (just a typo actually), but I'm not going to delete it because other people have already gained rep by giving  answers. Please tell me if this is not the right way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ids are case sensitive, your id is `goleft` but you try to look it up with `goLeft`.

Comment: A very, very, very stupid mistake. Thank you for the catch, I will accept your answer once SO will allow me (in 10 minutes)!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest a minor change to your code that might make your life easier:

```
<img id="goleft" onclick="leftArrowPressed()" src="x"/>
<img id="goright" onclick="rightArrowPressed()" src="x"/>
```

Change your `changePic()` function to take a string instead of an element and this will make things a little easier on you.

If you want to stick to your current implementation: you use `goLeft` in the lookup and it should be `goleft`. Case sensitive!

Comment: Unfortunately it's easier for me to stick to the current implementation (cause this is a simplified version of the real code) but thanks anyway for the tip!